# How can I generate continuous Poisson distributions in Java?

Tags: java, statistics, normal-distribution, poisson

I need a method or class that generates a continuous Poisson distribution, able to take a non-integer mean for setup and then outputting cumulative/integrated probabilities across a non-integer input range. For example, a Poisson distribution with λ = 1.23 and returning the probability that 4.56 < X < 7.89.

All the stats packages I could find online only accept integers for x (discrete Poisson).

Comment: If it doesn't exist, you will probably have to make your own.

Comment: I think 'R' might help. Here are some stackoverflow answers: [ http://stackoverflow.com/tags/poisson/hot ]

Answer (score 0):

[From apache commons:](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/PoissonDistribution.html)

To get the probability that 4.56 < X < 7.89 for example use cumulativeProbability(7.89) - cumulativeProbability(4.56)

Comment: The docs indicate cumulativeProbability only takes an int parameter. If it could take a floating point parameter like you showed then it would be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: "A poisson distribution is a discrete probability distribution that expresses the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time and/or space if these events occur with a known average rate and independently of the time since the last event" [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) 

The number of events occurring in an interval is integer. In other words P 4.1 <X<5.9 = P(X=5).

For the cumulative distribution a floating point input is equivalent to the floor of that value (7.8 -> 7 etc)